# Is wild camping allowed in the Maldives?

Tags: camping, maldives

Are there any places in the Maldives in which we can legally camp?

Comment: Been investigating the Maldives recently.  My understanding is it's basically all atolls, with private resorts on them.  Camping isn't really a thing there. Also it's crazy expensive :/

Comment: @MarkMayo They've actually liberalised lately and it's now possible to visit the regular non-resort islands and stay in homestays etc. No idea about camping though.

Comment: @MarkMayo  any idea about other islands in the world ?

Comment: @jpatokal any idea about other islands in the world ?

Comment: @jpatokal yeah, I've read some TT forums about home-stays

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi that's pretty broad. I can suggest Aogashima tho :) Did that 3 years ago, camping on a volcano inside a volcano.  But this is getting off topic - I'd suggest joining the [chat].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible but not formally allowed. You have to ask for permission as a favor and then maybe you are allowed

Check: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g293953-c198707/Maldives:Backpacking.In.The.Maldives.Different.html

> Camping Approval: Camping is possible, but not formally allowed, only as a favor with no guarantee, depends on how many people, days, and how you ask - best to go and negotiate directly with the Island Chief."

You should search and talk with this "Island Chief" but I dont know how and if at the end will be allowed. Anyways I will expect that it is not alowed due to the amount of tourism. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although the government loves tourists who spend money, and most of the land is either owned by the government or people, you can go to  Hulehule island and camp all you want.

Ziad EL Shurafa

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a proof of accommodation/reservation to immigration upon arrival in the Maldives. If you do not have they might forbid you to enter the country.

The resorts will not allow you allow you to enter their island without having a room booked.

The local islands (where locals live ) might allow you to plant your tent but you will first need the authorization from the island chief.

Comment: And how can we contact an ISLAND-Chef ?